# After resize of vector then why can I not increment vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a data structure that I can cycle round, sort of a circular list, using a vector.  I resize which I am thinking should initialise the underlying array with ten elements.  I don't understand why I cannot advance the iterator.  Can someone please help.

I cannot use push_back() because that will always append to the end which is not what I want.

```
// re-use start of vector when get to end
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

class printme {
public:
   void operator() (int val) {cout << val << endl; }
};


//get a debug assertion - message says: vector iterators incompatible
//I assume this means that it is invalid after previous it++
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   vector<int> myvec;
   myvec.resize(10);  //underlying array now has size=10 elements
   vector<int>::iterator it = myvec.begin();  //point to start of array
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      if(it == myvec.end())           //on 2nd iteration crashes here - invalid iterator
         it = myvec.begin();

      myvec.insert(it++, i);
   }

   //print contents of vector - check 90-99 printed
   for_each(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), printme());

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT
Changed loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
   if(it == myvec.end())
      it = myvec.begin();

   *it++ = i;
}
```

I didn't properly understand insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you expect in output - I believe you misunderstood what `insert` is doing.
Implement your loop in this way (without insering - just replacing). `std::vector<>::insert` increments the size of your vector by one - I believe it is not what you expect.

Do not do this:

```
myvec.insert(it++, i);
```

But this:

```
 *it++ = i;
```

Then you'll get your desired ouput:

```
   //print contents of vector - check 90-99 printed
   for_each(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), printme());
```

Comment: Yes or myvec[inserter++ % 10] = i; - but your version removes need for int intserter to keep track of index.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators can be invalidated by some operations on a vector - including `insert`. You'll need to re-fectch `it` in order to be able to use it after the `insert`.

```
vector<int>::iterator it = myvec.begin();  //point to start of array
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
   if(it == myvec.end())           //on 2nd iteration crashes here - invalid iterator
       it = myvec.begin();

   myvec.insert(it++, i);
   //it can be invalid here, re-fetch it
   it = myvec.begin();
}
```

Comment: Can I re-fetch but not change position?  Something like insert(val) then 'refresh' then increment?

Comment: @user619818: `insert` returns an iterator pointing to the new element, you can use that. Either `it = myvec.insert(it, i);` or `it = myvec.insert(it, i) + 1;`, I'm not sure which you want.